# Create generic/base form class regardless if activity or fragment

Tags: java, android, solid-principles

I'm trying to create a generic/base form regardless if it is an `activity` or `fragment`. To make it simple, a `Form` can submit so:

```
class BaseFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public abstract void submitForm();

  @Override
  public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    ConstraintLayout activityBaseForm = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base_form, null);
    FrameLayout frameBaseForm = activityBaseForm.findViewById(R.id.frame_base_form);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameBaseForm, true);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).setOnClickListener(v -> submitForm()) // for the sake of simplicity, there's a button that will trigger submitForm() method

    super.setContentView(activityBaseForm);
  }
}
```

Here, I just include some default layout for a form, and a button for submit that triggers the abstract method `submitForm()`. But, this is only for android `activities`. How can I make this also available for `fragments` without writing a `BaseFormFragment`? I don't want to repeat default behaviors from `activity` to the `fragment` and vice versa.

Comment: Write Business  logic in a presenter class and write a interface which impiments in Activity or Fragment which can be used to get Views you require

Comment: Can you give atleast an example? Im also thinking of an interface, but how do I put the logic on a single class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider it as a sample Presenter class which handle your button click and get all form fields and send to server

```
public class MyPresenter {
     private MyPresenterIView iViewInstance;

        public MyPresenter(MyPresenterIView iView){
          this.iViewInstance=iView;
        }

        public void onSubmitClick(){
          //write your logic here
         String fieldOneText=iViewInstance.getFieldOneText();
         sendToServer(fieldOneText);
        }

        private void sendToServer(String stringInfo){
        //send info to server
        }

    }
```

MyPresenterIView Interface

```
public interface MyPresenterIView{
  String getFieldOneText();
}
```

And use Presenter in your Activity or Fragment

```
//implement MyPresenterIView to your Activity or Fragment 
public class MyActivity extent SomeActivity implements MyPresenterIView{
private MyPresenter myPresenter;

//in onCreate or onCreateView(if its  a fragment) initialize myPresenter
protected void onCreate(..){
myPresenter=new MyPresenter(this);//this will enforce Activity/Fragment to implement IView
}


@Override //comes from MyPresenterIView
public String getFieldOneText(){
return ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttext_field_one)).getText().toString().trim();
}
}
```

Comment: hm, I think this is more on the presentation layer structure part, what I'm trying to do is to lessen the boilerplate inserted on xml (submit button for example), by having it on the parent class instead of adding it on each xml

Comment: You can create one xml and use it in both fragment and activities, right? 

>>but how do I put the logic on a single class?
Use solution above its reduce boilerplate code.

Guide me to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: I did stick to `activity` only, what I've stumbled on is that `fragment` is being held by `activity`, I just hide show if the specific form `fragment` is shown. Well, I've used also your suggestion, I also create a `BaseFormPresenter` for handling the default methods of my `presenter`